# connecting couchbase with camel

Tags: apache-camel, couchbase

I am trying to connect to couchbase through with following customroute configuration in java

```
                            from("cxfrs://bean://rsServer")
                   .choice()
                   .when(header("operationName").isEqualTo("getCity"))
                   .setHeader(CouchbaseConstants.HEADER_ID,constant("#"))
                   .to("couchbase:http://"couchbase-ip"/Hotels?operation='GET'")
                   .end()
                   .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
```

I want to give path param for my rest service to be provided as document id for retrieval from couchbase. Problem is Output returned is Arraylist of whatever is my path param.

Comment: As Couchbase may return more than one result row, it is reasonable that the result is a list, isn't it?

Comment: You can add a log to see if the couchbase return the response back.